# Android: item list click on JSON generated list view - unable to click

Tags: java, android

I am getting a JSON from a url to generate a list view of contact names & numbers. I intend to make it where users can just tap on the contact name or phone to make a call directly. But I am having problem to get the tap on the item detected. I tried to put a log on the 'onItemClick' but it seems that it is not being called. Can you help see where I did wrong? Here is my code

```
            package com.example.hk.sample;

            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashMap;

            import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
            import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
            import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
            import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
            import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
            import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
            import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
            import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ListAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class AllAccepted extends Activity {

                ListView list;
                TextView phone;
                TextView name;

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                //URL to get JSON Array
                private static String url;
                //JSON Node Names
                private static final String TAG_OS = "myjson";
                private static final String TAG_VER = "phone";
                private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
                JSONArray android = null;
                //String matchId = Singleton.getInstance().getMatchIdString();
                String matchId = "80";

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.all_accepted); 

                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                    url = "http://demo.com/list.php?match_id="+ matchId; 

                    Log.e("final view", "final layout array list");
                    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                    new JSONParse().execute();

                    final Button btnHistory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goHome);
                    btnHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(myIntent);

                        }
                    });   

                }

                protected void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("item clicks", "selected: " + position);
                }


                private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
                    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
                   @Override
                   protected void onPreExecute() {
                       super.onPreExecute();
                       phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listPhone);
                       name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listName);
                       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllAccepted.this);
                       pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                       pDialog.show();
                   }
                   @Override
                   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                       // Getting JSON from URL
                       JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                       return json;
                   }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                               // Getting JSON Array from URL
                               android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                               for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                               JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                               // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                               String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                               String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                               // Adding value HashMap key => value
                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                               map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                               map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                               oslist.add(map);
                               //list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllAccepted.this, oslist,
                                       R.layout.all_accepted_layout,
                                       new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                                               R.id.listPhone,R.id.listName});
                               list.setAdapter(adapter);

                               }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                    }
               }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                } 

                @Override
                public void onBackPressed() {
                }

            }
```

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION FOUND:

add this into onCreate method

```
                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                            Log.e("item clicks", "selected: " + position);
                            String item = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                            String contactNum = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listPhone)).getText().toString();

                            Log.e("phone number", contactNum);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactNum));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

thanks to Kunu for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this on your onCreate()

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Log.e("item clicks", "selected: " + position);
                String contactNum = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listPhone)).getText().toString();
                phoneCall(contactNum);
            }
});
```

and don't forget to import `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;`

After retrieving the number try this to make a call

```
public void phoneCall(String number)
{
            String phoneCallUri = "tel:"+number;
            Intent phoneCallIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
            startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked, but how do I get the phone string of the selected item? Also if possible a sample code to make a call too. Thanks!!

Comment: Try this in your onItemClick() method to retrieve phone number associate with a row
String contactNum = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listPhone)).getText().toString();

Comment: yup, it works perfectly. You have a sample code for making a call to the number retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

to set the itemClickListener use :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(ActivityName.this);
```

Override the method, and also inside the xml
set the `focusableInTouchMode` to false, and also `focusable` to false for the textviews

Hope that helps

Comment: where should I put this code line? I tried to put inside onCreate list.setOnItemClickListener(AllAccepted.this);
 but then I got an error for setOnItemClickListener say I need to cast argument AllAccepted.this, but that also did not work

Comment: make sure that you have listView = (ListView)findViewById(id here) called first before calling listView.setOnItemClickListener.. Also put the onItemClick line in the onCreate method.

Comment: I've put in this on the onCreate method -> list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //list.setOnItemClickListener(AllAccepted.this);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(AllAccepted.this);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

             Log.e("item clicks", "selected: " + position);
            }
        }); but still same error

Answer (score 0):

in OnCreate     `list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {});`and then Add unimplement method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView lView ;
String[] ara={"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ara);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    lView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
}
```

}